# Handling multiple uploads of images with Angular multer Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, multer

I'm facing something weird when I try to upload images using angular multer and nodejs.
I am working on an ecommerce project and i want to store separately images of products (the main image 'imageVitrine', and others images grouped in an array).

My problem is that when i send images from the client side throught  http request for the server side, and i do a console.log of req.files, i just receive data for the single image (ImageVitrine) and not also for the grouped images array .

I've notice that images send through images array are available but only on req.body and not on req.files as they used to.

On the client side I've send those images by creating a formData object and appending those files respectively with 'imageVitrine' and 'images' entry names.

Can some one explain me why i have images array data on req.body not on req.files like imageVitrine as the official documentation of multer explain?

Some codes

On the server

```
//Extensions de fichiers autorisées
const FILE_TYPE_MAP = {

    'image/png':'png',
    'image/jpg':'jpg',
    'image/jpeg':'jpeg',

}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

    //Here we define the error when trying to load another file than an image
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {

        isValid = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let uploadError = new Error('Image invalide');

        if(isValid){
            uploadError = null
        }

      cb(uploadError, 'public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        
      const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      const fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-');
      cb(null, `${fileName}-${Date.now()}.${extension}`  )
    }
  })
  
const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage })



//The corresponding router 

router.post('/', uploadOptions.fields([{ name: 'imageVitrine'},{ name: 'images'}]), async(req, res)=>{


    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.file)
}
```

The client side

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){

this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      imageVitrineProduct: ["", Validators.required],
      imagesProduct:["", [Validators.required]]
    });
}

//Function that handle the save of un new product
  onSaveProduct(){

    //Construction of the product to save based on productForm values
    const newCreatedProductFormData = new FormData();

    newCreatedProductFormData.append('imageVitrine', this.productForm.controls['imageVitrineProduct'].value);
    newCreatedProductFormData.append('images', this.productForm.controls['imagesProduct'].value);


    this.productsService.addProduct(newCreatedProductFormData)
    .subscribe(
      (result) =>{

          //affichage du message lors d'un ajout sans erreur
          this.messageService.add({severity:'success', detail: result.message});
          lastValueFrom(timer(2000))
          .then( 

            //après l'ajout d'une catégorie on revient à la liste
            () =>{ this.location.back()});
    },
    () =>{
      this.messageService.add({severity:'error', detail: 'Erreur système: faire appel au webmaster'});
    }
    )
  
  }
```

Thank you.
I'm a french speaker so i apologize for my English level XD .

Comment: Can you share the code how are you uploading multiple images?

Comment: Both backend and frontend code in combination would be easier to catch the problem. 
Also, why not just use multiple images approach that covers the single image use case as well ?

Comment: I'm working on an ecommerce project i have decides to separate the main image of a product with and the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys i've found what was going wrong.
I explain it below if can may be help someone one day XD .

What i was missing is that i should've create a loop of my images array  and append each time i've an image in the same formData variable and not just append the entire array of files to the formData.

So considering that this is my array of files

```
arrayOfFiles[];
```

The mistake i was doing was appending this array on formData like this :

```
formData.append('images', arrayOfFiles);
```

What i should've done :

```
for(let img of arrayOfFiles){
   formData.append('images',img);
}
```

This solve my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).